# Product of a left outer join in linq not keeping the right side

Tags: linq

I'm trying to do a left outer join using linq.  I swear this worked a couple of weeks ago when I wrote and tested it, but now it's not actually joining the two sides.

```
var combined = from h in historyTable
join d in (from d in deviceTable where d.DeviceType == 5 select d) on h.SerialNumber equals d.SerialNumber into dh
from subDH in dh.DefaultIfEmpty()
select subDH;
```

This should work as a left outer join, right? I'm not missing something crucial, as all this is supposed to do is join each table at the SerialNumber.  I've made an SQL version, and it works just fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM [deviceTable] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM [historyTable]
    ) AS [t1] ON [t0].[SerialNumber] = [t1].[SerialNumber]
WHERE [t0].[DeviceType] = 5
GO
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Could you describe what is contained in `combined` after you perform the command? Is there a runtime error? A compile time error? If there is output, how is it different from what is expected?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL has the left and right sides round the other way. Try this:

```
var combined = from d in deviceTable
               where d.DeviceType == 5
               join h in historyTable on d.SerialNumber equals h.SerialNumber
                      into dh
               from subDH in dh.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new { d, subDH };
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is on what side doesn't matter to me at the moment, I'm just trying to figure out why dh and subDH are being regarded as solely of the same table type as deviceTable.  Shouldn't it be a combination of the two, i.e. have both tables' columns?

Comment: @Tory: No - `dh` contains the elements of the "right" table corresponding with the current element of the "left" table - that's why I've got a projection to an anonymous type in my sample query.

Comment: Ok.  I don't understand why the programmers chose to have it so that the new table is just the right table grouped by the left table, but that is the way it is, apparently.  I've got it working the way I need it to, so thank you for your help.